# Streaming opencv Video

Tags: opencv, streaming, gstreamer

I need some ideas about how to stream video feed coming from opencv to a webpage. I currently have gStreamer, but I don't know if this is the right tool for the job. Any advice on using gStreamer or any hyperlinks to tutorials would be helpful and appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV doesn't provide an interface for streaming video, which means that you'll need to use some other techonology for this purpose.

I've used GStreamer in several professional projects: *this is the droid you are looking for*.

Comment: speaking of droids, I have need of putting this on android. Any suggestions?

Comment: It does not provide an interface but you can (more or less) easily convert data obtained using gstreamer to a OpenCV program.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any experience w/ streaming OpenCV output to a website. However I'm sure this is possible using gstreamer.

Using a gstreamer stream, it is possible to get data and convert the data in to OpenCV format. I recommend you read up on GstAppSink and GstBuffer.

Basically, if I remember correctly, you must run a pipeline in the a background thread. Then using some function in gst_app_sink, you can get the buffer data from the sink.

A quick lookup on the issue, you had to use GST_BUFFER_DATA for this

I remember having to convert the result from yCBCr to bgr, a collegue had problems as the conversion of opencv was inadequate. So you might have to write your own. (This was back in the IplImage* days)